# How to show sequence of partial sum $S_n$ is bounded given the the sequence $a_k$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Define the sum, $S_n =  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k$

Given that the sequence $a_k$ is bounded above, so can I show that $S_n$ is bounded above this way?  :

Since $a_k$ is bounded above, there exists a real number $M$ such that $a_k \leq M$, for all $k$. So, we have,
$$S_n =  \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k = a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n \leq M+M+M+\cdots+M =nM$$

Hence $S_n$ is also bounded above.

Is it correct?

Comment: Do you have to do all that work? Doesn't $S_n\le S_n$ prove that $S_n$ is bounded above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I choose $a_k=1$ for every $k$; you did not forbid it. Then we can have $M=1$. So $S_n=n$, which is not bounded above. Your proposition is not true.